# Regarding binding data to gridview in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

Hi
I have session array values fetching from other page. I want all the values to be bind with gridview. But i am getting only last value of the array. I used following code:

```
int[] a = (int[])Session["values"];
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            str = "select * from Quest_Info where Quest_id='" + a[i] + "' order by Quest_id";
            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(str, sqlconn);
            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
            da2.Fill(ds2, "Result");
            reviewgrid.DataSource = ds2;
            reviewgrid.DataBind();
        }
```

Why i am getting only first value?
Asp.net c#
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're executing a new command for every value in the array, and rebinding the grid.

A grid can only have one datasource.  Every time you call DataBind(), it removes whatever was in the grid before, and binds it to the new source.

You need to modify your query to return all the rows that you want at once, rather than executing the query multiple times and returning a single row each time.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're iterating through the list of values and resetting the select command for the data binding for each one.  The datagrid can only have one data binding, so it's the last one that's set is what you get.

You'll need to do something like:

```
int[] a = (int[])Session["values"];
string s = String.Join(",", a);    // join the array into a comma-separated string
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select * from Quest_Info where Quest_id in (" + s + ") order by Quest_id";
reviewgrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: why u used String.Join(",", a); this statement. here its not working its giving error

Comment: Your SQL statement needs to be something like `Select * from Quest_Info where Quest_id in (2,4,6) order by Quest_id`.  This will get the rows where the Quest_id is 2, 4 or 6.  This assumes that Quest_id is a numeric column.  If it's a character type then the bit in parens should be ('2','4','6').

Comment: i used code : for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                str = "select Quest_id from Quest_Info where Quest_id='" + a[i] + "' order by Quest_id";
                SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(str, sqlconn);
                DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
                da2.Fill(ds2, "Result");
                reviewgrid.DataSource = ds2;
                reviewgrid.DataBind();
            }
but it still gives last record

Comment: i used your code in my code, let me know string s = String.Join(",", a);    this should be as it is or any changes in this code

Comment: i am not getting i used array then also its giving only one value in my updated code

Comment: That code gives error like "string.join has some invalid arguments"

Comment: You need to include the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.